# Does English "day" really come from PIE *dʰegʷʰ- (“to burn”)?

Tags: etymology, english, proto-indo-european

***[day](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/day#Etymology)***

> From [Middle English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Middle_English) *[day](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/day#Middle_English)*, from [Old English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_English) *[dæġ](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/d%C3%A6g#Old_English)* (“day”), from [Proto-West Germanic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proto-West_Germanic_language) *[*dag](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-West_Germanic/dag)*, from [Proto-Germanic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proto-Germanic_language) *[*dagaz](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Germanic/dagaz)* (“day”), from [Proto-Indo-European](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proto-Indo-European_language) **dʰogʷʰ-o-s*, from *[*dʰegʷʰ-](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Indo-European/d%CA%B0eg%CA%B7%CA%B0-)* (“to burn”).
>
> Cognate with [Saterland Frisian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saterland_Frisian_language) *[Dai](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Dai#Saterland_Frisian)* (“day”), [West Frisian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/West_Frisian_language) *[dei](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dei#West_Frisian)* (“day”), [Dutch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dutch_language) *[dag](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dag#Dutch)* (“day”), [German Low German](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low_German) *[Dag](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Dag#German_Low_German)* (“day”), [Alemannic German](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alemannic_German) *[Däi](https://en.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?title=D%C3%A4i&action=edit&redlink=1)* (“day”), [German](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_language) *[Tag](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Tag#German)* (“day”), [Swedish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swedish_language), [Norwegian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norwegian_language) and [Danish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Danish_language) *[dag](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dag#Danish)* (“day”), [Icelandic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Icelandic_language) *[dagur](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dagur#Icelandic)* (“day”). Cognate also with [Albanian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Albanian_language) *[djeg](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/djeg#Albanian)* (“to burn”), [Lithuanian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lithuanian_language) *[degti](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/degti#Lithuanian)* (“to burn”), [Tocharian A](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tocharian_languages) *[tsäk-](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ts%C3%A4k-#Tocharian_A)*, [Russian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russian_language) *[жечь](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%87%D1%8C#Russian)* (žečʹ, “to burn”) from *degti, *[дёготь](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B4%D1%91%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%8C#Russian)* (djógotʹ, “tar, pitch”), [Sanskrit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sanskrit) *[दाह](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E0%A4%A6%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%B9#Sanskrit)* (dāhá, “heat”), *[दहति](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E0%A4%A6%E0%A4%B9%E0%A4%A4%E0%A4%BF#Sanskrit)* (dáhati, “to burn”), [Latin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin) *[foveō](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/foveo#Latin)* (“to warm, keep warm, incubate”).
>
> [Latin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin) *[diēs](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dies#Latin)* is a [false cognate](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/false_cognate); it derives from [Proto-Indo-European](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proto-Indo-European_language) *[*dyew-](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Indo-European/dyew-)* (“to shine”).

***[Proto-Indo-European phonology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proto-Indo-European_phonology#Coronals.2Fdentals)***

> Coronals/dentals[edit]

> The standard reconstruction identified three coronal/dental stops: */t/, */d/, */dʰ/. They are symbolically grouped with the cover symbol T.
> In so-called "thorn clusters" of the form TK in all branches except Anatolian and Tocharian a metathesis occurred, resulting in dorsal-coronal clusters of non-obvious phonetic makeup. **Metathetized and unmetathetized forms survive in different ablaut grades of the root *dʰégʷʰ "burn" (whence also English day) in Sanskrit, dáhati "is being burnt" < *dʰégʷʰ-e- and kṣā́yat "burns" < *dʰgʷʰ-éh₁-.** See the section on PIE phonological rules, below, for more discussion and examples.

I doubt this etymology just because I can't find any reference of this kind of saying that **PIE *dʰegʰ-** "day" and ***dʰegʷʰ-** "burn" are cognates.

**PS**: the reconstructions are based on [***here***](http://www.kloekhorst.nl/KloekhorstPIEThornClusters.pdf), in footnote 8 on page 2 of which the author even deny this connection and **E. day** comes from **PIE *dʰegʰ-** "to repeat itself (over and over again); cycle".

Answer (score 8):

In PIE we have

***dheĝhr*** *day* (root dheĝh- "cycle")

***dhoğhos*** *burning* (root dheğh- "to burn")

***dius*** *sky, daylight* (root dei̯- "sky")

All three are not related or their relation is unknown. Traditionally English "day" is considered to derive from the PIE root for "burn", although the author whom you link in the question points out that it is more likely to derive from PIE root meaning "cycle" which already was used for "day" and "yesterday" (***dhĝhi̯es***) in PIE, and which also gave for example, Russian "den'" "day" which indicates that the PIE word for day had an r/n stem (-r suffix in Nominative and -n in other cases), and as such, very archaic.

An ironic consequence of this hypothesis if we accept it would be that the both parts of the English word "*yesterday*" originate from the same root: the yester- part is from ***dhĝhi̯es*** "yesterday" while the second part is from ***dheĝhr*** "day".  The corresponding PIE form would be ***dhĝhi̯esterom dheĝhr*** (according the rules, the first word due to large consonant cluster would be pronounced starting with ĝh- already in PIE). It is unknown whether such form was used already in PIE or originated later, but it does not seem impossible especially given that ***dhĝhi̯es*** is adverb rather than a noun. For instance, in Russian you can say "вчера" "yesterday(adv.)" and "вчерашний день" "yesterday(adj.) day".

Comment: Wow `dheĝhr` looks joltingly like Georgian [`დღეს` (dḡes)](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E1%83%93%E1%83%A6%E1%83%94%E1%83%A1) "today"! It turns out a connection has been hypothesized.

Comment: @hippietrail nice observation! Also in Adygh language дыгъуасэ (dygyase) is "yesterday".